# how to loop three variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello would like to ask how do I loop this javascript.
looks like if I put some for loop into it, it will overwrite my first variable.

```js
$('#select-box1').change(function(){
    $('#changing-img1').attr('src',$('#select-box1').val());
});
$('#select-box2').change(function(){
    $('#changing-img2').attr('src',$('#select-box2').val());
});
$('#select-box2').change(function(){
    $('#changing-img3').attr('src',$('#select-box3').val());
});
```

Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Why do you need loops?

Comment: What HTML are you using this with?  What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you think you need to loop? Is the image not being replaced? If so try adding a unique variable (like time in seconds) to the src of the image field. eg `$('#changing-img1').attr('src',$('#select-box1').val() + '?' + Date.now() );`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a loop, consider `data` attributes and a common class.

By attaching your `change` event to the common class, you can then use the changed element's `data-id` attribute to determine which image should change.

```js
$('.select-box').change(function() {
  const imgId = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $(`#changing-img${imgId}`).attr('src', $(this).val());
}).change();
```

```css
img { display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-box" data-id="1">
  <option value="https://picsum.photos/id/123/100/100">One</option>
  <option value="https://picsum.photos/id/841/100/100">Two</option>
</select>

<select class="select-box" data-id="2">
  <option value="https://picsum.photos/id/123/100/100">One</option>
  <option value="https://picsum.photos/id/841/100/100">Two</option>
</select>

<select class="select-box" data-id="3">
  <option value="https://picsum.photos/id/123/100/100">One</option>
  <option value="https://picsum.photos/id/841/100/100">Two</option>
</select>

<img id="changing-img1" />

<img id="changing-img2" />

<img id="changing-img3" />
```

Comment: wow this is so cool, this is exactly what I need it. looks silly to keep repeat the same script so am trying to improve it. Thank you very much